# React components with predefined prop value like html tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add values to my components prop that intellisense can recognize that and show it, so I can select them easily and not having any typo.
I'm also using react@18 and JS. functional components.

```
<button type="values that intellisense would show" />
<MyCustomButton type="values that intellisense would show" />
```

I've tried using JsDoc but that's not as good as html tags:
[in case of having an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MR6i.png)
I want to make my components like this.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on your IDE and stack. Which ide do you use? Do you use TypeScript?

Comment: @pe.kne I'm using vscode, Im planning for TS but right now im not using it, is there a way to do it with TS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use React [Typechecking with propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to handle it.

forexample :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

or you can use Typescript, that's  what typescript good at.
here is codesandbox example for prop checking https://codesandbox.io/s/test-tsx-forked-67765?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: You should also include `ProtoTypes.oneOf(['some', 'specific', 'value'])` since it seems like it was asked for intellisense for enum like types